# wamp, roots.io/sage, kirki and path

Tags: wordpress, wampserver

I use the starter theme roots.io/sage and kirki for theme customizer on windows 10 with wampserver.

I have a problem with the path used by kirki :

```
[code]
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
http://localhost:3000/www.site.fr/wp-content/themes/siteC:wampwwwwww.site.frwp-contentthemessitelibkirki/assets/js/kirki-tooltip.js?ver=4.3.1
[/code]
```

Comment: I can see that would not please you, but what is your question

Comment: It is recommended to use Virtual hosts when you install WP see this for help on [setting up Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)